# How do you create a named fork called rsrc on linux?

Tags: linux, gentoo, raspberry-pi, hfs+

I have gotten an experimental raspberry pi kernel image with hfsplus support built and gentoo installed on the same filesystem.  I read that accessing filename/rsrc can access the resource fork.  I found that attempts to use touch to create an empty resouce fork gives back an access denied error even as root. *How do you create a named fork such as rsrc under linux?*

Also I ask, what format does the resource map in classic MacOS happen to use (it is okay to explain with either c data types (i.e. char[4]) or even resource types (i.e. CSTR))?

Once I have the answer to the second question I will build a linux based resource manipulation library in c++. I already know how to code a simple doom wad editor/parser in c++.

or I could also ask, how does one set extented attributes under linux?

Answer (score 0):

"how does one set extented attributes under linux?" => `setfattr`

But as for your original question, the hfsplus implementation in Linux doesn't seem to implement creating resource forks.